# Blackjack card counting, with one whole deck should the "count" end on zero?

Tags: statistics

When playing blackjack if you are card counting for a single deck, should the count always come to zero at the end of the deck? Wouldn't it depend on strategy and a corresponding betting table?

Would the optimum card counting strategy end you with a count of zero for one deck?

Comment: Not well-defined enough to be a mathematical question - you haven't defined any of your terms mathematically, assuming way too much knowledge about card counting on the part of the answerers.

Comment: So rephrase it with maths, more info about what counting is, and I can ask it again?

Comment: Yes, if you have a well-defined mathematical problem, feel free to ask it here.

Comment: I'll put a link here to it when I can get it written out.

Comment: I would figure people on here would understand what I mean. Its not worth it at this point to explain to the laymen what card counting is and what it is used for just so I can ask a question about it to someone with more knowledge than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the system of card counting.

With the Hi-Lo count (the most common), the count should sum to $0$ after every single card in the deck has been played.

```
2 3 4 5 6    = +1 (low cards)
7 8 9        =  0 (neutral cards)
10 J Q K A   = -1 (high cards)
```

Using this chart, it is easy to see that there is an equal number of $+1$ cards and $-1$ cards.  Over the course of the deck, there will be a total of $20$ low cards and $20$ high cards (along with $12$ neutral cards).  This means that the count at the end must equal zero.

Several  of the more advanced systems, however, will not have a balance between positives and negatives, and they will then have a non-zero count at the end of the deck.